# What file for setting default keyboard Layout

Tags: 11.04, keyboard

I set the wrong keyboard layout while installing ubuntu and now it reverts back to English every time I reboot.

I heard this is normal behaviour, but I want to change the default layout from English the German. I found that I have to edit etc/X11/xorg.conf, BUT that file does not exist on 11.04.

Can someone guide me to the file that initiates this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default keyboard layout for GNOME w/ Unity Shell by pressing the Ubuntu logo on the top left of your screen and in the search box typing: `keyboard` and then selecting the `keyboard` application and going to the *layouts* tab.

If you would like to change the default keyboard layout for your console (terminal) you can do so by opening up a terminal and typing: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.

Comment: I feel pretty retarded, there was a button, apply for whole system >.<

Comment: This does not seem to be available in 11.04. I have no *layouts* tab.

Answer (score 5):

That option to change it globally has disappeared in newer Ubuntu versions. It can be canged in the file /etc/default/keyboard (reboot afterwards).

Answer (score 4):

Just switched from US layout to German (on 12.04);

To configure the keyboard layout for tty1:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

/etc/default/keyboard

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```